# Problema en el ingreso de datos por teclado con java

Tags: java, bucle-for

estuve tratando de hacer este programa , el principal problema es que solo me deja ingresar el valor que le quiero dar al `numeroN` , despues ya no me deja escribir por consola y en la sumatoria me sale que es igual a cero , queria saber si alguien me puede decir en que me equivoque .

```
// Hacer un programa que permita sumar los primeros numeros N pares.

int numeroN = 0;
int numero = 0;
int sumatoria = 0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese el valor que desea asignarle al numero N : ");
numeroN = sc.nextInt();


for (int i = 1; i < numeroN; i++) {

    System.out.println("Ingrese un numero : ");

    if ((numero % 2) != 0) {

        numero = sc.nextInt();

    }

    else if ((numero % 2) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error! El numero ingresado es par.");
    }

    sumatoria += numero;

}

System.out.println("La sumatoria es : " + sumatoria);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for (int i = 1; i < numeroN; i++) {

```
System.out.println("Ingrese un numero : ");
//numero es igual a cero en esta parte 
if ((numero % 2) != 0) {// el remanente de dividir 0/2 es 0 entonces no leé nada 
    numero = sc.nextInt();
}
```

pueder acerlo de la siguiente manera

```
 System.out.println("Ingrese un numero : ");
    numero = sc.nextInt();
    if ((numero % 2) != 0) {
     sumatoria += numero;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ya lo pude solucionar :D , Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Tu programa no hace lo que dices en la descripción. Debes revisar los pasos usados en tu programa.

Nota que inicializas `numero` en 0 y solo lees el número cuando `numero % 2 != 0`. Es decir, nunca lees ningún número.

```
// inicializa el número
int numero = 0;

// si el número es impar (nunca)
if ((numero % 2) != 0) {
  // lee otro número.
  numero = sc.nextInt();
}
```